# How to delete alerts/events from RHEV-M 3.2

Tags: alerts, rhev

I can't find a way to clear events/alerts from RHEV-M 3.2. Kindly let me know if any of you know a way to do that.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible. Open a case with Red Hat support.

Comment: I still can't find way to do that. Look like I gotta open case to Red Hat...

Comment: Red Hat support said that it is impossible to clear the log manually as of RHEV 3.2. They mentioned log rotation for RHEV log is 30 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible if you manually clear the SQL tables holding the logs. Highly not recommended to even touch without someone from RH support holding your hand